# How to match a key in an object with a given string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to match a key in an object with string. It works fine if an object contains single key but if it contains many keys it fails to match.can anyone help me with this?

object

```
let object = {
    user_name: "sample",
    user_email: "sample@gmail.com"
}
```

trying to match with given string

```
for (let key in dict) {
    var res = key.match(/email/g)[0];
    console.log(res)
}
```

expected output

```
user_email
```

Comment: your first element does not match. So key.match returns undefined. Undefined[0] breaks your loop

Comment: @The_Original do you have any alternative way to get the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```js
let dict = {
    user_name: "sample",
    user_email: "sample@gmail.com"
}

var check;
var res;
for (let key in dict) {
    check = "";
    check = key.match(/email/g);
    if (check) {
        // return the matched element like "email" only
        // res = check;
        // return the element which contains "email" in "key"
        res = key;
    }
}
console.log(res);
```

Just change `key.match(/email/g)[0];` with `key.match(/email/g);` and it works just fine. You don't need to define `[0]`.

Comment: Hey great!. it is working expected. is there any way to eliminate null values ?

Comment: @SudharsanVenkatraj I have updated the code. Please check now.

Comment: is it possible to give string in place of variable(variable name instead 'email')

Comment: @SudharsanVenkatraj code updated, please check now.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```js
let object = {
  user_name: "sample",
  user_email: "sample@gmail.com"
}

let variable = 'email'  // New edit as per first comment

Object.keys(object).forEach(element => {
  if (element.includes(variable)) {
    console.log(element)
    console.log(object[element])
  }
})
```

Comment: is it possible to give string in place of variable(variable name instead 'email')

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting multiple keys which matches the required patter you can map through and filter

Use `String.prototype.includes` when not looking for pattern matches

```js
let object = {
 user_name: "sample",
 user_email: "sample@gmail.com",
        user_secondary_email: "sample@gmail.com"
}

let output = Object.keys(object).filter(key => key.includes('email'));
console.log(output)
```

Comment: is it possible to give string in place of variable(variable name instead 'email')

Comment: @SudharsanVenkatraj yes you can use variable also just store the `email` in some variable and use `key.includes(variable)`

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the match is successfull:

```js
let dict = {
    user_name: "sample",
    user_email: "sample@gmail.com"
}

for (let key in dict) {
    var res = key.match(/email/g);
    if (res) { // match
        console.log(dict[key])
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to give string in place of variable(variable name instead 'email')